# Выравнивание по левому краю pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть файл excel с выравниванием текста по левому краю.  Почему при открытии  через pd.read_excel датафрейм  выровнен по правому краю и как это исправить?

Comment: Вообще пандас больше предназначен для анализа данных, а не для эстетического их просмотра.

Comment: а где смотрите -то? VS CODE или Spyder?